# Change textbox input by script in JS

Tags: javascript, web

Looking for some help, I'm coding a script right now and I need to change a text box inside the HTML page it's running on.

I need to change the value of the `inputwood` ID for example But the use of `document.querySelector("#inputWood").value=0;` just doesn't work.

```js
document.querySelector("#inputWood").value=0;
```

```html
<ul class="clearfix">
   <li class="assignWood " style="width:131px">
      <div class="clearfix">
         <input id="inputWood" type="number" class="textfield" maxlength="4" min="0" max="1290" size="3" name="wood" data-max="1290" value="860">
         <div class="plusminus">
            <div class="plus" id="plusWood"></div>
            <div class="minus" id="minusWood"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="assignLuxury " style="width:128px">
      <div class="clearfix">
         <input id="inputLuxury" type="number" class="textfield" maxlength="4" min="0" max="1164" size="3" name="luxury" data-max="1164" value="776">
         <div class="plusminus">
            <div class="plus" id="plusLuxury"></div>
            <div class="minus" id="minusLuxury"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="assignScientists " style="width:109px">
      <div class="clearfix">
         <input id="inputScientists" type="number" class="textfield" maxlength="4" min="0" max="256" size="3" name="scientists" data-max="256" value="256">
         <div class="plusminus">
            <div class="plus" id="plusScientists"></div>
            <div class="minus" id="minusScientists"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="assignPriests " style="width:130px">
      <div class="clearfix">
         <input id="inputPriests" type="number" class="textfield" maxlength="4" min="0" max="992" size="3" name="priests" data-max="992" value="816">
         <div class="plusminus">
            <div class="plus" id="plusPriests"></div>
            <div class="minus" id="minusPriests"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="assignCitizens" style="width:149px">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="שמור">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Any help?

Comment: It works well. See snippet above.

Comment: The script code I've written doesn't change the value at all.

Comment: Well the problem might be somewhere else. The code you gave us works well as you can see if you hit "Run code snippet" button. Does it give you some `console` errors?

Comment: Is Java relevant here?

Comment: @VLAZ No, it's not.

Comment: `userscript.html?name=... Uncaught ReferenceError: updateContext is not defined`
    `at mineGoldInCity (userscript.html?name=...`
    `at Window.doWorkInCity (userscript.html?name=...`

Errors like this

Comment: @AvivBenShahar This is obviously something completely different. I don't see any `updateContext` variable in the code. You have an error in the code elsewhere.

Comment: FIXED it! the updateContext shouldn't be there - I put a null instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put javascript code in function and assign to onclick-event of button. In your snippet js code runs immediately and we see only "0" value in iput field.

```
   <li class="assignCitizens" style="width:149px">
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="שמור" onclick="changeit()">
```

```
function changeit(){
   document.querySelector("#inputWood").value=0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use like this
const wood= document.querySelector("#inputWood");
wood.value;

Comment: How exactly could this help?